# How to inject multiple models in one controller method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have one controller BulkActionApiController, and here the method

```
/**
 * Mass delete models
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $model
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function massDelete(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    try
    {

        $model::whereIn('id', $request->ids)->delete();

        return response()->json('Successfully deleted', 200);
    }
    catch (\Throwable $t)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to detect which model passed to this method and delete records of this model. How can i implement this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please define your model in top of you controller page like 

use App\YourModel;

Comment: I've define it, but it not work

Answer (score 1):

You can place the following check.

`if($model instanceof SomeModel){
   .
   .
   .
   .
}`